# How to work with 2 arrays having field from one array dependent on field from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two arrays namely arrayGuest and arrayRent. These are arrays of objects. Both objects and consequently, arrays have one field common that is GuestID. I want to create a list that when both guestID's match, displays fields from both arrays together.

These are the two objects:

```
class Guest
{
    guestID: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    panCardNumber: string;
    address: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    typeOfRoom: string;
}


class Rent
{
    guestID:number;
    amount:number;
    dateOfPayment: Date;
}
```

and here are the two arrays:

```
let arrayGuests:  Array<Guest> = [
    {guestID:1,firstName:"Jay",lastName:"Shetty",panCardNumber:"FSDDE2235A",address:"150ft Ring Road",city:"Rajkot",state:"Gujarat", typeOfRoom: roomType.AC},
    {guestID:2,firstName:"Pooja",lastName:"Mehta", panCardNumber:"FDSSQ5464J", address:"Bopal",city:"Ahmedabad",state:"Gujaray",typeOfRoom:roomType.NonAC},
    {guestID:3,firstName:"Rahul",lastName:"Joshi", panCardNumber:"ERTEQ2316H", address:"Thaltej",city:"Ahmedabad",state:"Gujarat",typeOfRoom:roomType.AC},
    {guestID:4,firstName:"Komal",lastName:"Kaushik", panCardNumber:"VBCCK7418Q", address:"Vasai",city:"Mumbai",state:"Gujarat",typeOfRoom:roomType.AC},
    {guestID:5,firstName:"Raj",lastName:"Khatri", panCardNumber:"KOILE5951B", address:"Connaught Place",city:"Delhi",state:"Delhi",typeOfRoom:roomType.NonAC}
]


let rentArray : Array<Rent>= [
    {guestID:1,amount:5000,dateOfPayment:new Date("2022-03-01")},
    {guestID:2,amount:5000,dateOfPayment:new Date("2022-03-01")},
    {guestID:3,amount:5000,dateOfPayment:new Date("2022-03-01")},
    {guestID:4,amount:5000,dateOfPayment:new Date("2022-03-01")},
    {guestID:5,amount:5000,dateOfPayment:new Date("2022-03-01")},
]
```

I want a result somewhat like,
**GuestID:1, Name : xyz, amount = 5000**

Comment: please add your code. what goes wrong?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. How do I link Guest's ID to Rent's ID?

Comment: @ChaitanyaBathia Are the arrays sorted?

Comment: I have kept the arrays limited to 5 entries for now, statically and both are sorted on GuestID, values 1 to 5.

Comment: it all depends on the size of your Arrays and the usage. if it is only for a punctual and infrequent return, then use a search. if your arrays are small then merge them, otherwise you will have to create a new array to make the links between the IDs, etc. In short, your question is badly put, and in any case SO, is not a site to obtain free code but to provide mutual assistance.

Comment: @MisterJojo I am new to Typescript and did not know what approach to take, so I approached SO, and like you said, SO is to provide mutual assistance, I wasn't looking to obtain free code either. Thanks for your suggestion anyway and I'll keep your point in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said both the arrays are sorted, that means that we can go by the index value and simply merge them.

```
interface Guest {
    guestID: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    panCardNumber: string;
    address: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    typeOfRoom: string;
}

interface Rent {
    guestID: number;
    amount: number;
    dateOfPayment: Date;
}

type Merged = Guest & Rent;

const arrayGuests: Array<Guest> = [
    {
        guestID: 1,
        firstName: 'Jay',
        lastName: 'Shetty',
        panCardNumber: 'FSDDE2235A',
        address: '150ft Ring Road',
        city: 'Rajkot',
        state: 'Gujarat',
        typeOfRoom: 'AC',
    },
    {
        guestID: 2,
        firstName: 'Pooja',
        lastName: 'Mehta',
        panCardNumber: 'FDSSQ5464J',
        address: 'Bopal',
        city: 'Ahmedabad',
        state: 'Gujaray',
        typeOfRoom: 'NoneAC',
    },
    {
        guestID: 3,
        firstName: 'Rahul',
        lastName: 'Joshi',
        panCardNumber: 'ERTEQ2316H',
        address: 'Thaltej',
        city: 'Ahmedabad',
        state: 'Gujarat',
        typeOfRoom: 'AC',
    },
    {
        guestID: 4,
        firstName: 'Komal',
        lastName: 'Kaushik',
        panCardNumber: 'VBCCK7418Q',
        address: 'Vasai',
        city: 'Mumbai',
        state: 'Gujarat',
        typeOfRoom: 'AC',
    },
    {
        guestID: 5,
        firstName: 'Raj',
        lastName: 'Khatri',
        panCardNumber: 'KOILE5951B',
        address: 'Connaught Place',
        city: 'Delhi',
        state: 'Delhi',
        typeOfRoom: 'NonAC',
    },
];

const rentArray: Array<Rent> = [
    { guestID: 1, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
    { guestID: 2, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
    { guestID: 3, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
    { guestID: 4, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
    { guestID: 5, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
];

// Create a function which takes our guest array
// and rent array as arguments
const mergeArrays = (guests: Guest[], rent: Rent[]): Merged[] => {
    // Immediately return a new array, which will be
    // returned by the .map method
    return guests.map((guest, i) => {
        // Whatever is returned from each iteration becomes the
        // new value at that position in the array.
        // Return new object with all of our guest item properties,
        // Spread out all rent properties for the matching index.
        return {
            ...guest,
            ...rent[i],
        };
    });
};

console.log(mergeArrays(arrayGuests, rentArray));
```

Compiled:

```js
"use strict";
const arrayGuests = [
    {
        guestID: 1,
        firstName: 'Jay',
        lastName: 'Shetty',
        panCardNumber: 'FSDDE2235A',
        address: '150ft Ring Road',
        city: 'Rajkot',
        state: 'Gujarat',
        typeOfRoom: 'AC',
    },
    {
        guestID: 2,
        firstName: 'Pooja',
        lastName: 'Mehta',
        panCardNumber: 'FDSSQ5464J',
        address: 'Bopal',
        city: 'Ahmedabad',
        state: 'Gujaray',
        typeOfRoom: 'NoneAC',
    },
    {
        guestID: 3,
        firstName: 'Rahul',
        lastName: 'Joshi',
        panCardNumber: 'ERTEQ2316H',
        address: 'Thaltej',
        city: 'Ahmedabad',
        state: 'Gujarat',
        typeOfRoom: 'AC',
    },
    {
        guestID: 4,
        firstName: 'Komal',
        lastName: 'Kaushik',
        panCardNumber: 'VBCCK7418Q',
        address: 'Vasai',
        city: 'Mumbai',
        state: 'Gujarat',
        typeOfRoom: 'AC',
    },
    {
        guestID: 5,
        firstName: 'Raj',
        lastName: 'Khatri',
        panCardNumber: 'KOILE5951B',
        address: 'Connaught Place',
        city: 'Delhi',
        state: 'Delhi',
        typeOfRoom: 'NonAC',
    },
];
const rentArray = [
    { guestID: 1, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
    { guestID: 2, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
    { guestID: 3, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
    { guestID: 4, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
    { guestID: 5, amount: 5000, dateOfPayment: new Date('2022-03-01') },
];
const mergeArrays = (guests, rent) => {
    return guests.map((guest, i) => {
        return Object.assign(Object.assign({}, guest), rent[i]);
    });
};
console.log(mergeArrays(arrayGuests, rentArray));
```

Read about the [Array.prototype.map() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Learn about the [...Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: The code works and it got me the result I wanted, but I can't understand what happened here:


`const mergeArrays = (guests: Guest[], rent: Rent[]): Merged[] => {
    return guests.map((guest, i) => {
        return {
            ...guest,
            ...rent[i],
        };
    });
};`

Comment: @ChaitanyaBathia I'll add comments explaining it

Comment: @ChaitanyaBathia Also, I really wouldn't recommend learning TypeScript before you learn regular JavaScript fundamentals. It will only make things more difficult for you in the beginning. For your sake, switch to JavaScript for now

Comment: I am currently undergoing training for my job, and I have learned basic javascript, at beginner level. I also understood that you have taken in the concept of spread and rest operators, just didn't understand how it worked.